# How to remove the extra task properties which are fetched in the response body while calling an API?

Tags: asp.net, .net-core, jwt

This is the TokenHandler:

public Task CreateAdminTokenAsync(Admin admin)
{

```
        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(configuration["Jwt:Key"]));

        var credentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        //Create Claims
        var claims = new List<Claim>();
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.GivenName, admin.Name));
        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email, admin.Email));

        claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimsIdentity.DefaultRoleClaimType, "Admin"));


        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
            configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
            claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),
            signingCredentials: credentials);

        return Task.FromResult(new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token));
        
        }
```

This is my controller:
public async Task AdminLoginAsync(Models.DTOs.LoginRequest loginRequest)
{
//Check Username and Password

```
            var user = await adminRepository.AuthenticateAdminAsync(loginRequest.Username, loginRequest.Password);

            if (user != null)
            {
                //Generate JWT token and send it back
                var token = tokenHandler.CreateAdminTokenAsync(user);
             return Ok((token));
            
            }
            return BadRequest("Username or Password is Incorrect.");
    }
```

The Outcome is:
{
"result": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9naXZlbm5hbWUiOiJOYW5kaW5pIFRyaXBhdGh5IiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMueG1sc29hcC5vcmcvd3MvMjAwNS8wNS9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvZW1haWxhZGRyZXNzIjoibmFuZGluaXRyaXBhdGh5MTk5OUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiJQYXNzZW5nZXIiLCJleHAiOjE2NjYwNzI3ODksImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjcwNTQvIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NzA1NC8ifQ.HltuOc9KYTJaxKjs4s7OXQWwPcLjMCP3-J4SS3YPfAI",
"id": 1,
"exception": null,
"status": 5,
"isCanceled": false,
"isCompleted": true,
"isCompletedSuccessfully": true,
"creationOptions": 0,
"asyncState": null,
"isFaulted": false
}

But the desired outcome is:
{
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy54bWxzb2FwLm9yZy93cy8yMDA1LzA1L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9naXZlbm5hbWUiOiJOYW5kaW5pIFRyaXBhdGh5IiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMueG1sc29hcC5vcmcvd3MvMjAwNS8wNS9pZGVudGl0eS9jbGFpbXMvZW1haWxhZGRyZXNzIjoibmFuZGluaXRyaXBhdGh5MTk5OUBnbWFpbC5jb20iLCJodHRwOi8vc2NoZW1hcy5taWNyb3NvZnQuY29tL3dzLzIwMDgvMDYvaWRlbnRpdHkvY2xhaW1zL3JvbGUiOiJQYXNzZW5nZXIiLCJleHAiOjE2NjYwNzI3ODksImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vbG9jYWxob3N0OjcwNTQvIiwiYXVkIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9sb2NhbGhvc3Q6NzA1NC8ifQ.HltuOc9KYTJaxKjs4s7OXQWwPcLjMCP3-J4SS3YPfAI

}

Comment: The Outcome is: { "result": (The token), along with the following properties "id": 1, "exception": null, "status": 5, "isCanceled": false, "isCompleted": true, "isCompletedSuccessfully": true, "creationOptions": 0, "asyncState": null, "isFaulted": false }

Comment: Thank you CodeCaster it worked I added a await keyword. in var token=await tokenHandler.CreateAdminTokenAsync(user);

Comment: Sorry, I totally misread that. That's the solution indeed.